# Play video from oracle database stored in blob - Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is it possible load blob (video) in player (interactive report or plsql dynamic content) in oracle apex?

For example:

```
select 
ID, 
NAME,
decode(NVL(dbms_lob.getlength("BLOB"),0),0,NULL,
       '<video width="400" controls><source src="' ||apex_util.get_blob_file_src('P18_BLOB',IMG_ID)||'" type="video/mp4"></video>') "VIDEO"
from VIDEO;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Click here to see run time Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb2it.png)    For Interactive Report:

```
(1) Create ITEM (in this example - P3_VIDEO)
    Type: Hidden
    Source: Type => Database Column
            Database Column => Your blob column in the table that has video content
    Used: Always replacing existing value in session state.

(2)Create ITEM (in this example - P3_ID)
    Type: Hidden
    Source: Type => Database Column
            Database Column => Primary key column of the table has video content
    Used: Always replacing existing value in session state.

 (3)Create a page process
    Type: Automatic Row Fetch
    Table name: Your table that has video content
    Primary Key Column: Primary key column of the table has video content
    Primary Key Item: P3_ID (In this example)
        
 (4) SQL Query of the IR
       SELECT ID,'<video width="320" height="240" controls>
       <source src="'||apex_util.get_blob_file_src ('P3_VIDEO',ID, 
       p_content_disposition => 'inline')||'" type="video/mp4">
       our browser does not support the video tag.
       </video>' as VIDEO
       FROM VIDEO;
  
 (5) select the column - VIDEO (in this example)
     Type - Plain Text
     Security - Escape Special Characters - No
```

Comment: The sql code was not appearing correct because of formatting was not correct. I corrected the formatting now and its visible :) .. Thanks for the point, i did not notice that

Comment: Type: Automatic Row Fetch is legacy any other solution?